# Adding new compute nodes to a devstack installation

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

I have been following the the devstack multi node lab set up guide to setup a devstack cloud on a desktop and 3-4 older laptops that I have lying around. I am a complete newbie to this setup. I have followed the guide exactly and I can get the desktop as a controller and one of the laptops as a compute node.

I have two problems here.

1. The major one is that I cannot seem to add any more compute nodes than the one I have already added. So I have both the desktop and 1 laptop as the compute nodes. I use the same local.conf file as given in the guide, with the only difference being the floating ip range, which I have given as 172.25.1.128/29
2. The secondary problem I have is that I cannot ssh into an instance which starts up with a fixed range ip (which is 10.4.128.0/20, according to the guide). My network is on 172.25.1.0/24. But once I associate a floating IP(which is 172.25.1.128/29) with the instance, i can ssh into the instance using it. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Has someone come across the same problems?

This is the guide I used - http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/guides/multinode-lab.html

Answer (score 0):

You Can always add the Node manually, if its on Virtualbox you can Create a node and link it to the Main node where you boot your openstack, your master node for installation.

In Devstack or Fuel Openstack you always have to make sure of your Eth Cards, the Ip's. When ever you add another node make sure to add an Network card to receive the boot image, and another eht depending on your network setup